# Retornar Latitude e Logitude, para campos do meu formulário com Javascript - Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google, maps

O meu problema com a latitude e longitude foram resolvidos, agora estou com dificuldades para retornar estes valores dentro do meu formulário, vou deixar a baixo o link para demonstração.

[Link com o projeto](http://agenciapost.com.br/mapa.html)

"Eu estou usando o seguinte script do Google Maps para retornar estabelecimentos, porem no meu marker alem do nome do local gostaria de retornar, latitude e longitude."

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: { lat: -23.562428,
              lng: -46.652863 },
    zoom: 13
  });

  var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */ (document.getElementById('pac-input'));
  var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
  });

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);

    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    if (!place.geometry) {
      window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
      return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }

    marker.setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
      url: place.icon,
      size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
    }));

    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

    var address = '';

    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
      ].join(' ');
    }

    infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }); // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places // Autocomplete. function setupClickListener(id, types) {

  var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);

  radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    autocomplete.setTypes(types);
  });
}

setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
```

Answer (score 3):

Onde vc tem o código:

```
var address = '';
if (place.address_components) {
address = [
  (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
  (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
  (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
].join(' ');
}

infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

Altere a linha para ler infowindow

```
infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + place.geometry.location.lat() + ',' + place.geometry.location.lng());
```

Comment: Acredito que agora ficou melhor, @bfavaretto.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, agora eu tenho a necessidade de passar estes valores para os meus campos no formulário. Segue link para exemplo http://agenciapost.com.br/mapa.html

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui resolver fazendo da seguinte forma, assim consegui resgatar todos os dados para o meu formulário.

```
    var place = this.getPlace();

  $("body").find("#txtNome").val(place.name );
  $("body").find("#txtEndereco").val(place.formatted_address);
 $("body").find("#txtLatitude").val(place.geometry.location.lat());
 $("body").find("#txtLongitude").val(place.geometry.location.lng());
if (!place.geometry) {
  window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
  return;
}
```